# Which parameter is used to unique identify a 'call' in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

There are a bunch of ID's or similar in WebRTCStats, but the documentations seems to be pretty scarce as to what they represent (at least from what I've been able to dig up).

The use case here is to be able to get both communicating peers from a set of data that are send/receiving media with one another (i.e. the entire session). At the moment, I have a set of data that is from one devices perspective, such as the RTT from device 1 to and from device 2. But now I'd like to find device 2 and get the RTT from it as well for that particular call - basically pair them up.

I assume each call or media session has some GUID that they both share, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RTCPeerConnection object for which you get statistics using the getStats call only describes a single session to start with.

How you match up that data from different devices depends on how you send them to a common endpoint. In general there will not be a 1:1 correlation between data from one endpoint and another since statistics such as bytesReceived are generated at different points in time.

What you can do is to send an identifier along with those data that identifies the local and remote end of the call (which you might consider to be a guid). [rtcstats.js](https://github.com/lifeonairteam/rtcstats) supports that kind of approach but its not anything standardized.

Comment: Oh interesting. So there isn't a GUID for each peer in WebRTC out of the box?

Comment: Chrome had a googLibjingleSession_ statistic somewhere in the legacy google getStats but it wasn't a guid either. In general this is the job of the signaling protocol.